# Why isn't the udp packet received? (Can be seen in Wireshark)

Tags: c#, udp

I have a problem with receiving a given udp packet in my C# program.

The code in question is as follows:

```
//create transport
m_conn = new UdpClient(new IPEndPoint(m_interface_ip, 0));
m_conn.DontFragment = true;
m_conn.EnableBroadcast = true;
m_conn.Connect(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(destination_ip), m_port));
m_conn.BeginReceive(new AsyncCallback(OnDataReceived), m_conn);

//create packet
//...

//send
m_conn.Send(buffer, length);
```

The `OnDataReceived` function is just an empty function with a breakpoint.

I've disabled my firewall and the program to 'allowed list'.

The 'request' and 'response' can be seen in Wireshark. See attached pcap file. The packets seems to be valid. The device is a certified Profinet device (in case it makes a difference).

And yet I can't seem to suck up the 'response' into my `OnDataReceived` function.

Am I missing something fundamental? Is there something unusual with the udp/ip header perhaps?

[Attached Wireshark output](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/65221538/udp_packets.pcapng)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the answer. It seems that the device is responding to the request from a different source port. This means that the Windows drivers (and Wireshark) marks the messages as unrelated. (Not responding from the same socket/port is a rather foolish thing to do and I'm guessing it's an error.)

However, it can be fixed. Instead of the 'unicast' socket above, one have to create a server socket. Like so:

```
//create transport
IPEndPoint local = new IPEndPoint(m_interface_ip, 0); //bind to any free port
m_conn = new UdpClient();
m_conn.Client.Bind(local);
m_conn.EnableBroadcast = true;
m_conn.BeginReceive(new AsyncCallback(OnDataReceived), m_conn);

//create packet...
//...

//send
m_conn.Send(buffer, length, new IPEndPoint(m_destination_ip, m_port));
```

This will annoy the firewall, but it seems to work.